# Conditionally require code in commonJS AMD module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, commonjs, js-amd

I'm trying to write a cross-browser extension for Firefox and Chrome. Firefox uses the commonJS specification and Chrome just lumps everything into the global namespace like a webpage.

In order to be able to write reusable code, I'm trying to use requireJS to lood code in the Chrome extension, that way I can write commonJS modules and have them work in both environments.

I'm running into a problem when I need to conditionally require modules. For example, Firefox provides access to a `simple-storage` module which you should use to access the local storage. In chrome, I need to use the localStorage API that they provide. So, I've been trying to do this:

```
// storage.js
define(function(require, exports, module){
  var store;      

  try {
    // This module will only be available in the FF extension.
    store = require('simple-storage').storage
  } catch(error) {
    // If it's not available, we must be in Chrome and we
    // should use the localStorage object.
    store = localStorage
  }

  // Use the store object down here.
});
```

However this doesn't seem to work. When I try to load the Chrome extension I get the following error:

[image: Chrome error]

Is there a better way to require modules with a fallback?

Comment: Might not be completely relevant here, but 'finally' will be run whether or not the try block throws an exception. So even if your try block passes, the finally block will overwrite store. Is that what you wanted? If not, I believe a try/catch is what you're after.

Comment: And if your try block throws an error, the finally block is executed and the error is rethrown after that

Comment: Opps sorry, I meant `catch`. Either way, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two caveats here:

1) Detect if chrome is running

```
// detects webKit (chrome, safari, etc..)
var isChrome = 'webKitTransform' in document.documentElement.style
```

2) Requirejs will parse the `define()` function and search for `require('module')` calls. To prevent the error on chrome you have write the `require` in some way that when `requirejs` parses the function body it does not recognize the call as a module dependency:

```
if (isChrome)
   // use localStorage
else {
   // set the module name in a var does the trick,
   // so requirejs will not try to load this module on chrome.
   var ffStorageModule = 'simple-storage';
   return require(ffStorageModule);
}
```

Comment: The module 'simple-storage' needs to be loaded previously, otherwise you get a similar error: ```Uncaught Error: Module name "simple-storage" has not been loaded yet for context: ```